# PHPUnit, тестирование вывода в stderr по маске

Tags: php, phpunit

Допустим есть функция логирования

```
class Logger {
    public function log($message) {
        fwrite(STDERR, json_encode([time() => $message]));
    }
}
```

Контроль над `$message`, конечно есть, а вот над `time()` - не очень.

Как с помощью PHPUnit можно протестировать, что в STDERR вывелась строка, совпадающая с шаблоном? (а если сразу проверить на корректный JSON, то вообще замечательно)

```
{%i:"error"}
```

Comment: вы про моки? если вам нужно точно знать, что вернёт time() замойкате значение, которое должно вернуться при вызове этой функции

Comment: @EugeneNagornichyh сейчас сделал через assertStringMatchesFormat замокав методы с fwrite на echo. Но как-то оно некрасиво. Хотелось бы обойтись без моков, каким-то образом перехватив stderr